# CreateBufferedCopy extremely bad performance

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

We have a typical IIS hosted, c# wcf web service and want to record all incoming requests. For this purpose I'm using a message logging inspector class as defined below. I call CreateBufferedCopy on it to get a BufferedMessage to pass it to the logging function and to make it processable another time for the service.
For some reason the CreateBufferedCopy call is painfully slow.
The request I used for testing has a size of aprox. 1MB and this single call took nearly 3.5 seconds!!! Why?
Without this logging functionality, a call to our web service took 300ms,
for the same request, including receiving the request, processing it, calling another backend webservice, processing its response and return our response.
Adding 3.5 seconds to every request only for logging purposes is absolutely inacceptable.

I have the following class:

```
public class MessageLoggingInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var bufferedMessage = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        watch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("AfterReceiveRequest::CreateBufferedCopy: {0} elapsed.", watch.Elapsed);

        request = bufferedMessage.CreateMessage();

        LogMessage(bufferedMessage.CreateMessage(), "request");

        return null;
    }

    private void LogMessage(Message message, string filenameAppendix)
    {
        // do some logging stuff
    }
};
```

**AfterReceiveRequest::CreateBufferedCopy: 00:00:03.4431423 elapsed.**

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up some profiling. You already have a general idea where the slowdown is occurring, so it should be easy. If you have Visual Studio 2015, run your project with profiling turned on and you will find exactly what/where is so slow in no time.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use VS 2013

Comment: After some diving into the Framework I found the reason for this Problem.
The request contains an XML-Attribute with about 900.000 chars length (don't ask me why...).
When this Attribute is copied, the underlying XmlBinaryWriter reads this value in 256 Byte chunks. Unfortunately the complete attribute will be build up by a stupid concatenation of those chunks using the += operator.

Comment: This leads to over 3600 allocations and copy instructions while the buffer size grows by 256 with each iteration....
Stupid implementation!